# ATA secure erase really long using a SED harddrive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, security, sed

I have a ST2000DM002 hard drive (SED) from Seagate, I have done a secure erase with hdparm on Linux, it was more than 1 hours ago and the command didn't returned yet and the HDD is fully spinning out since that

The password was previously set then with hdparm -I /dev/sda, I checked that the HDD was "not frozen" then I issued the security erase command hdparm --user-master u --security-erase mysecurepassword /dev/sda

That's it and the command didn't returned since then, I have a SSD from toshiba and doing this manipulation I have secure erased the drive within fews seconds I don't understand why it's doesn't work the same way with this HDD from seagate anyone got a clue about this ?

Answer (score 2):

Writing over 2TB on a PATA drive *will* take an extremely long time.  Expect it to take a couple of hours.

Comment: Thank for your answer, yes I know, however my drive is a Self Encrypting Drive so it should normally be able to erase the data within seconds like my SSD, I'm missing something ? Should I send other commands to have the expected behavior

Comment: first off SSDs and HDD are completely different.  You cannot compare the two.  Also, you need special software to securely erase SSDs, as common secure erase methods do not work on SSDs - as they work differently than HDDs.

Comment: I think you totally miss the point, my Seagate hard drive is a SED, so I don't have to overwrite all my sector to securely erase my data, perhaps I have not issued the right command to say to the drive to erase the encryption key idk...

Comment: We get your point, and understand what you're saying, but you're still incorrect. If you're going to wipe even an SED HDD, you will do so by manually writing values over all of the sectors. There may be a command that will tell the SED to simply delete the key data, but that does not erase the data, it would simply place an obstacle before decryption. SSDs have a command that tells every sector to wipe themselves nearly simultaneously. This is how they can erase much more quickly than an HDD, SED or not.